# How to fill autocomplete options list from REST API in angular 13? My code doesn't work properly and shows nothing in the list from the beginning

Tags: angular, angular-material, autocomplete

I used autocomplete angular material to list options loaded from REST API but my list shows nothing and is empty but after starting typing it shows the list.

I used `getData()` function to fetch data from API and fill `options` array but I think the list won't fill because `options` is an array and `filteredOptions` is and observable and `filteredOptions` will fill later. I don't know how to fix it.

I expected to see the list when I click on input field but it is empty.

Here is my codes:

**html:**

```
<form class="example-form">
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width" appearance="fill">
    <mat-label>Number</mat-label>
    <input type="text"
           placeholder="Pick one"
           aria-label="Number"
           matInput
           [formControl]="myControl"
           [matAutocomplete]="auto">
    <mat-autocomplete autoActiveFirstOption #auto="matAutocomplete">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let option of filteredOptions | async" [value]="option">
        {{option}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

**.ts file:**

```
import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl} from '@angular/forms';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map, startWith} from 'rxjs/operators';
import { AuthenticationService, Products_Header_VW } from '...';


@Component({
selector: 'app-test-second',
templateUrl: './test-second.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./test-second.component.scss']
})
export class TestSecondComponent implements OnInit {
myControl = new FormControl('');
options: string[] = [];
filteredOptions!: Observable<any>;

constructor(private auth: AuthenticationService) {
    this.getData().subscribe(x => {
      this.options = x;
    });
}

ngOnInit() {
    this.filteredOptions = this.myControl.valueChanges.pipe(
    startWith(''),
    map(value => this._filter(value || '')),
    );
}

private _filter(value: string): string[] {
    const filterValue = value;

    return this.options.filter(option => option.includes(filterValue));
}


//**** Get all product data and move it to a string ****
private getData(): Observable<string[]> {
    return this.auth.getallproductheadersvw()
    .pipe(
        map(
        x => x.data.map((y:Products_Header_VW) => y.Product_Title_Persian)
        )
    )
}
}
```

Thank you for your attentions.

Answer (score 1):

I subscribed `filteredOptions` inside `getData().subscribe()`. So `filteredOptions` executed after `getData` completed and problem solved.

```
ngOnInit() {

  this.getData().subscribe(x => {
    this.options = x;
    this.filteredOptions = this.myControl.valueChanges.pipe(
      startWith(''),
      map(value => this._filter(value || '')),
    );

  });
}
```

I think I could use `concat` operator too.

Answer (score 0):

if you try to remove filter to verify all data and after applying the filter to exclude all items starttwith ''''

Comment: try to add more words